# Adding a default string if list empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I'm writing out an aggregated list of statuses. It works fine except for the situation where there are none. At the moment, null is rendered and the position is empty.

```
item.Stuff.Where(e => Condition(e))
  .Select(f => f.Status)
  .Aggregate(String.Empty, (a, b) => a + b)
```

Now, I'd like to populate the table element with "*---*" in case the list is filtered down to an empty one by *Condition* but I can't decide on a method.

What would be a smooth way to approach it?

I've tried something like the atrocity below but it looks, well..., atrociously and it doesn't render right, neither. I get to see the actual source code line (preceded by *False* or *True*) instead of the values.

```
item.Stuff.Where(e => Condition(e)).Count() < 1
  ? "---"
  : item.Stuff.Where(e => Condition(e))
    .Select(f => f.Status)
    .Aggregate(String.Empty, (a, b) => a + b)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this. If the status list is reasonably small (otherwise one should use *StringBuilder* anyway and not string concatenation).

```
item.Stuff.Where(e => Condition(e))
    .Select(f => f.Status)
    .Aggregate("---", (a, b) => (a == "---") ? b : (a + b));
```

It checks if the default text was replaced and, if it was, it concatenates the next status element to the already existing text mass.

This will return "*---*" if and only if it's never evaluated, i.e. if the list is empty. Otherwise one would get the same result as previously.

---

If `Status` is an enum, and you only need the distinct statuses, you can use the behavior of the [Flags] attribute.

If you define the enum like this

```
[Flags]
enum Status
{
    None = 0,
    Active = 1,
    Inactive = 2,
    Pending = 4,
    Deleted = 8
    ...
}
```

you can just do:

```
item.Stuff.Where(e => Condition(e))
  .Aggregate(Status.None, (a, b) => a | b)
```

The result is a collection of all statuses that are present in the list, and the output is nicely formatted list (`Active, Inactive, Pending`) or `None` if it's never run.

Comment: +½ for neatness and +½ for *StringBuilder* remark. The list is very reasonably small, often only two or three elements, so plus-concat will do fine. The syntax is lengthy as it is already.   :)

Comment: You could omit the `Select` and just add `b.Status` in the `Aggregate` call to reduce char count :)

Comment: I'd give you +1 more if I could. Good point. Sadly, I cheated a bit - *Status* is an *enum* so I have to play with *ToString* and adding that to all the *a*'s and *b*'s would atrocitize the code additionally, I'm afraid. It'd render something like *(a.Status.ToString(),b.Status.ToString())*, wouldn't it? Nevertheless, a really good remark.

Comment: I've added some suggestions how you could handle enums

Comment: Really great suggestion - I'll put it in right away, mate. Thanks! I'd bounty you if I wasn't so sneaky on my reputation since they retracted 5000+ score for suspected cheating.   :)

Comment: np, glad I could help

Comment: Small issue remaining - I've asked it in [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061644/listing-a-field-from-all-the-entities-in-a-collection).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty).First();` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360179%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Example

```
var item =  item.Stuff.Where(e => Condition(e))
  .Select(f => f.Status)
  .Aggregate(String.Empty, (a, b) => a + b);

var newitem = item.DefaultIfEmpty(new Item() { i = 1, Status = "---" }).First();
```

Comment: I need that on a single line. I'm putting the stuff on a page using Razor.