# Listing a field from all the entities in a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, aggregate

I'm writing out an aggregated list of statuses. It works fine except for the situation where there are none. At the moment, null is rendered and the position is empty.

```
item.Stuff.Where(e => Condition(e))
  .Select(f => f.Status)
  .Aggregate("---", (a, b) => (a == "---") ? b : (a + b));
```

I've got [a suggestion for solution and improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056250/adding-a-default-string-if-list-empty/23056382?noredirect=1#comment35239418_23056382) as follows.

```
[Flags]
enum Status
{
    None = 0,
    Active = 1,
    Inactive = 2,
    Pending = 4,
    Deleted = 8
}

item.Stuff.Where(e => Condition(e))
  .Aggregate(Status.None, (a, b) => a | b.Status)
```

As I'm a great fan of simpler syntax, I love skipping the *Select* part. However, the result now is not all the elements listed. In fact, only a single one is listed (instead of five as previously) and *None* appears where there was a single status before.

Perhaps I'm too brain-stuck but I can't see why. And, consequently, not what I should do about it, neither...   :(

Comment: Where are the statuses coming from? If they are coming from an extenal system (i.e. a database) you might need to renumber the statuses there as well.

Comment: Put it as a reply so I can check it done as an answer. Godlike, dude. I just realized that the statuses are supposed to be multiply listed, though, so *a | a* needs to result in *aa* not just *a* but it doesn't matter. It was still godlikely done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the statuses are coming from an extenal system (i.e. a database) you might need to renumber the statuses there as well.

Note that this works only if you use power-of-two values as the values of the statuses.

Eg. if I use

```
[Flags]
enum Status
{
    None = 0,
    Active = 1,
    Inactive = 2,
    Pending = 3,
    Deleted = 4
}
```

then `Status.Active | Status.Inactive` will return `Status.Pending` (1+2=3).

Also, this way you only get a list of *distinct* used statuses, i.e. if you have 10 active and 5 pending items, you'll get `Active, Pending` as a result, without any frequency information.

If you need this information too, I would suggest doing some grouping, like:

```
string.Join(", ", item.Stuff.Where(e => Condition(e))
  .Select(f => f.Status)
  .GroupBy(status => status)
  .Select(group => string.Format("{0} {1}", group.Count(), group.Key));
```

this will result in "10 Active, 5 Pending" or an empty string if there are no groups.

---

EDIT: Now I think of it, `string.Join` might be a better solution to the original question as well (`IEnumerable.Aggregate` is a great method, but it might be an overkill). Just something like:

```
string.Join(", ", item.Stuff.Where(e => Condition(e)).Select(f => f.Status))
```